# How could I know the version of OS X by the installer?

Tags: macos

I have a mac os x installer and its version is 23.1. So I want to know the system version of OS X after I install it because I want to install 10.6.3 on my machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mount the installation medium, then navigate to `System/Library/CoreServices` on the image/DVD (in a Terminal window). You'll find a `SystemVersion.plist` file there that contains the build number and version of the OS.

This will likely be build 10A432 (10.6); as far as I know, Apple doesn't distribute standalone installers for point updates. If you're in the Mac Developer Program, you can download a delta update to 10.6.3 from [connect.apple.com](http://connect.apple.com).